# Setting layer properties using Python Init function?

Tags: pyqgis, layers

Is it possible to set the layer properties Python Init function field programmatically?

I've been looking through the [qgis 2.2 api](http://qgis.org/api/2.2) but can't seem to find anything on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after [QgsVectorLayer::setEditFormInit](http://qgis.org/api/2.2/classQgsVectorLayer.html#af378678add9d2e61ccd7baaab7ee27dc) and  [QgsVectorLayer::editFormInit](http://qgis.org/api/2.2/classQgsVectorLayer.html#af413649109543e5d741cabc6c708fb64). Both of these functions are available in the python bindings.